# automatic restore files and database for demo forum

Tags: exec

I want to set up a demo forum where users can try every function (including admin functions). Because user can easily "destroy" the demo forum with admin rights, I have to restore the database and all files every 24hours.
My file structure looks like this:

```
/demo
    /restore.phpx
    /backup
        /wcf
        /sqlBackup.sql
        /acp
        /cache
        /icon
        /..further directions
```

Absolute path to "demo": /www/htdocs/XXXXX/demo/

I tried a script like this (restore.phpx):

```
<?php
// delete all files in /demo
exec('rm  /www/htdocs/XXXXX/demo/');
// copy all files from the backup direction
exec('cp -r /www/htdocs/XXXXX/demo/backup/ .');
// restore database
exec('mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD DATABASE < /www/htdocs/XXXXX/demo/backup/sqlBackup.sql');
// chmod 
exec('chmod -R 0777 /www/htdocs/XXXXX/demo/');
?>
```

But nothing happens (no restore). Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- To delete all files in demo the command is 
           rm -r /www/htdocs/XXXXX/demo/

2.- You are trying to copy from a directory that you have previously deleted

I would do backups using a third party tool that you most like to have backups more controlled and restoring using a cron.daily script.